# Scala return a value from a for cycle

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have the following piece of code

```
def my_function(condition: Int=>Boolean): Int = {
  for (i <- 0 to 10)
    if (condition(i)) return i

  return -1
}
```

The code is simple: if some `condition` is met for a number between 1 and 10, return the number, else return invalid result (-1).

It works perfectly fine, but it violates some of the functional programming principles, because of the `return` in the `for` cycle. How can I refactor this method (I got unit tests, too) and remove the return statements. I suppose that I must use `yield`, but it seems to produce list, I just need one value.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is the functional translation of your code:

```
def my_function(condition: Int => Boolean): Int = {
  (0 to 10).find(i => condition(i)).getOrElse(-1)
}
```

Or more succinctly as:

```
def my_function(condition: Int => Boolean): Int = {
  (0 to 10).find(condition).getOrElse(-1)
}
```

I've used the `find` method which takes, as an argument, a function that produces a Boolean.  The `find` method returns the first item in the collection that satisfies the condition.  It returns the item as an `Option` so that if there is no satisfying item, then the result will be `None`.  The `getOrElse` method of `Option` will return the found result if there is one, and return `-1` if there isn't.

However, you should **not** use "error codes" like returning -1 in Scala programming.  They are bad practice.  Instead your should throw an exception or return an `Option[Int]` such that returning `None` indicates no value was found.  The right way to do this would be something like:

```
def my_function(condition: Int => Boolean): Option[Int] = {
  (0 to 10).find(condition)
}

println(my_function(_ > 5))   // Some(6)
println(my_function(_ > 11))  // None
```

Comment: You can even write `(0 to 10).find(condition(a, _)).getOrElse(-1)`.

Comment: @Hauleth, true!  I was trying not to be too cryptic with the syntax.

Comment: Shouldn't your `my_function` take an `Int => Boolean` like OP's, rather than an `Int`?

Comment: @Luigi, Yeah, weird.  OP must have edited it directly after posting because the version I copied and pasted was different.  I'll update.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the native collection method

```
def my_function(condition: Int => Boolean): Int =
  (1 to 10).find(condition).getOrElse(-1)
```

Usually in scala you should avoid "error code" using an Option return

```
def my_function(condition: Int => Boolean) : Option[Int] =
  (1 to 10).find(condition)
```

Similarly you can use a for-yield comprehension

```
def my_function(condition: Int => Boolean): Int =
  (for (i <- 1 to 10; if condition(i)) yield i).headOption.getOrElse(-1)
```

or with Option

```
def my_function(condition: Int => Boolean): Int =
  (for (i <- 1 to 10; if condition(i)) yield i).headOption
```

or use recursion as @Jan suggestion